# How can I set up Haskell stack to use the system compiler+libraries?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

More broadly, I'd like to be able to use Haskell Stack as a build tool for projects in a university class. The main issue I've run into is when students try to use Haskell stack to build their project, they very quickly run up against their space quotas, as stack installs a sandboxed GHC compiler and all of the libraries locally.

I would like to be able to add flags to the project file so that the system GHC and libraries are used to work around this. Right now our IT department has the system GHC part working, but stack is still installing all libraries locally.

I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I'd try [`system-ghc: true, install-ghc: false`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#system-ghc) and some LTS which uses the same GHC version as the installed one (otherwise, I think stack has to download it per-user).

Comment: Unfortunately, the LTS we're using doesn't have all of the packages necessary for this project.

Comment: @BenMacAdam Did you find some kind of workable solution? Our university IT team is struggling with the same issues.

Comment: I did not, sorry.